# for loop iterating over same item 3 times before moving on javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, for-loop

I've created a function that returns the longest word of a string. To achieve this the string has been split into an array and iterated through with a `for loop`.

For some reason the for loop is iterating 3 times over the same item before increasing its count ? There is no obvious error I can see.

What is happening here, how do I stop it ? Also is there a better way to achieve what I'm trying to do here ? I'm relatively new to javascript.

```
function longWord(str) {
var wordArr = str.split(' ');
var highest = 0;
var longestWd ;

for(var i = 0; i < wordArr.length; i++) {
    var temp = wordArr[i].length
   var word = wordArr[i];

    if(temp > highest) {
        highest = temp;
        longestWd = word;             
    }
        alert(longestWd);
        alert(highest);
}

}

longWord('this is a string with a longest word');
```

Comment: Of the first three words in your test sentence, which one is the longest?

Comment: In addition to the other answers, if you're including a library like Underscore or Lo-Dash, you can just pass a key function to `_.max` and use that to get the max element: `_.max(str.split(' '), function(word) { return word.length; })`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code is just fine. If you replace the alerts to a `console.log` call like this:

```
console.log(i, word, longestWd)
```

You can see it works as expectd:

```
0 "this" "this"
1 "is" "this" 
2 "a" "this" 
3 "string" "string"
4 "with" "string" 
5 "a" "string" 
6 "longest" "longest"
7 "word" "longest"
```

---

A nice way to do this can be by using [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) like this:

```
function longWord(str){
    return str.split(' ').reduce(function(a, b){
       return a.length > b.length ? a : b;
    });
}
```

> The `reduce()` method applies a function against an accumulator and each
>   value of the array (from left-to-right) has to reduce it to a single
>   value.

Comment: great answer to the "better way", still a mystery about the 3 times OP asked about though (btw, according to jsperf, this solution is much slower for some reason )

Answer (score 2):

Your alerts are inside of your loop. So, the longest word and its length will be alerted for each word that is tested.

For example:

```
TEST     LONGEST
----     -------
this     this    <- these are the three you are talking about
is       this    <- these are the three you are talking about
a        this    <- these are the three you are talking about
string   string
with     string
a        string
longest  longest
word     longest
```

Try moving the alerts outside of the for loop so that the alerts happen *after* all words have been tested, like this:

```js
function longWord(str) {
    var wordArr = str.split(' ');
    var highest = 0;
    var longestWd;

    for (var i = 0; i < wordArr.length; i++) {
        var temp = wordArr[i].length
        var word = wordArr[i];

        if (temp > highest) {
            highest = temp;
            longestWd = word;
        }
    }
    alert(longestWd);
    alert(highest);

}

longWord('this is a string with a longest word');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/L7HP5/

Comment: yours still run 3 times btw (if you put the alert INSIDE the loop, which, shouldn't have happened, and I think this is what OP asked)

Comment: @Noctis Sorry, I'm not sure what you mean. Can you help to clarify?

Comment: put the alert inside the loop, and you get each word outputted 3 times, which is what the OP asked about. (in his case, you might see all words, in yours, you just see the longest)

Comment: It is not testing the same word multiple times. It's just alerting the longest word once for every word tested. For the first three words tested, the longest word remains the same which might make it seem like its testing the same word three times. I have updated my answer with an example.

Comment: True ... true ... can't believe I missed that :) I think this answers OP question

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not wrong. it's just iterating 3 times over 'this' as it's the longest word.

**Based on your code:**

```
function longWord(a){
 a = a.split(' ');
 var b = a.length,
 c = '';
 while(b--){
  c = c.length < a[b].length ? a[b] : c 
 }
 return c;
}
```

**DEMO**

http://jsfiddle.net/8KQK9/1/

**PERFORMANCE**

http://jsperf.com/longword

Comment: i do it so i(and other ppl) can copy and past if i need the code in near future.I also do it by hand because minifiers can't properly handle shorthand and bitwise operators.

Comment: What minifiers are you using? No decent minifier will break your code.

Comment: i don't use minifiers. i learned to write using shorthand and bitwise operators. http://jsfiddle.net/YjCbM/1/. i also don't use jquery. i use notepad to write the code.or jsfiddle.no joke.

Comment: like it's hard for you to read code without whitespaces it's hard for me to read simple code full of new lines tabs and whitespaces.

Comment: Looks like you aren't joking. Programming languages are written for humans to read. Minifying them by hand gives you absolutely no benefit whatsoever and leaves you with an unmaintainable pile of text.

Comment: nothing with you ... i just added that so i can copy and past the latest version i wrote.

Comment: i always try to save bytes... especially for simple functions like that.. they work with every browser.. ie6 and up ... why should you need to read that code? here is a nice site about byte saving techniques. http://www.140byt.es/ with some very usefull functions.

Comment: And seriously ... just because you can't read a very basic javascript  shorthand operator or whatever.. you need to downvote ppl?

Comment: I downvoted your original answer because your code was poorly-written.

Comment: it was very nice written .. 3 lines of code inside a function without useless spaces , each line had his role .. and you say it's poorly written? .. no ... fabulous.